# Shared Preferences Location on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have developed a Import / Export feature for my app so uses can export the database and shared preferences to be used in another phone. This has worked fine up until I got myself a S3 and tried to do it.

After some work I got the database import / export to work (duel SCdards issue) but the shared preferences is still causing me trouble.

On a new install the import fails because there is no shared preferences file on the phone. Once I update an option the File is created (added in a check to see if the file on the phone exists)

This to create it

```
this.sharedprefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedprefres.xml", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This to check file is there

```
File sharedPrefencesFileOnPhone = new File(/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/, "sharedprefres.xml");

        if (sharedPrefencesFileOnPhone.exists()) 
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SP : Running Copy");
```

The Copy then seems to go though but none of the options are updated.

This all works on the emulator with no issues

The check only works once I have updated a option and the file is created which is given me to belive the shared preferences are saved.

Does the S3 hide the shared preferences somewhere else and if so is there some code for me to track it down that would work on multi phones

Thanks for your time

Comment: Service oriented architecture might be worth a look and have you time on the import export side of things. You could look at Google's services to see if they can support your data or maybe a custom service of your own.

Comment: Can you give a link for more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

`/dbdata/databases/package.name/shared_prefs/package.name_preferences.xml` (if it exists use it)

otherwise

```
new File(getFilesDir(), "../shared_prefs");
```

or

```
/data/data/package.name/shared_prefs/package.name_preferences.xml
```

Comment: I have tried File shared_prefs = new File(getDataDir(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()), "shared_prefs/"); and that outputs the file location I hardcoded above

Comment: give a try with paths given above and tell the situation. do you have tried with them ?